# Quick Return actionBar with viewPager not working as expected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout

I wanted to implement a Quick Return actionBar with viewPager.

I have a `scrollView` in my main fragment of `viewPager`. The `scrollView` contains a `textView` with some random long text.  I tried using this code but the `actionBar` is not hiding on scroll.

This is my `xml` file for the `MainActivity`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="example.srujan.com.sgtrv5.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

**Problem:**
The actionBar is not hinding at all. Can somebody please explain what is wrong with this code?

I guess the Java code isn't required here. Let me know anybody want me to post the java code as well

Comment: Any chance you've found a solution to this and could come back and answer your own question? I'm having the same problem.